# htaccess redirect example.com/about to https://www.example.com/about

Tags: .htaccess

The following code redirects many requests to https://www.example.com, but requesting example.com/about redirects to https://www.example.com. How can I make it redirect to the requested page (https://www.example.com/about)?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    <Files "*.txt">
      Require all denied
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Move `# Handle Front Controller...` rule at the bottom and retest in a new browser or clear cache

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to redirect all unavailable variation to home page, rather to relevant page or 404 page.

If it's so, then I must say it's best practice to have 404 page instead redirecting to home page.

Otherwise you can use below code for your purpose, just add below lines in your code and remove other redirections.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://domainname.com
```